# Auto Complete Hint with Material in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, autocompletetextview, material-components-android

I read doc in [material-text-field](https://material.io/archive/guidelines/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-layout) and there is auto-complete-textView on editText as hint not dropdown. You can see image below. But I can't do it. I try some code with textinputlayout and material-auto-complete-text like this

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til"
        ..>
               
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
       .../>


</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

in fragment

```
    ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
    items.add("Material");
    items.add("Design");
    items.add("Components");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,R.layout.item, items);
    TextInputLayout textInputLayout = findViewById(R.id.til);
```

and set adapter

```
((MaterialAutoCompleteTextView) textInputLayout.getEditText()).setAdapter(adapter);
    ((MaterialAutoCompleteTextView) textInputLayout.getEditText()).setText(adapter.getItem(1),false);
```

BUT the auto-complete-textview is suggesting the item on dropdown not on editText as a hint.

I want **AutoC**omplete as "AutoC" must be text and "omplete" must be hint

How can I do it ??

[image]

Comment: it is the normal behavior in the material components library

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT:

Is the following what you are looking for?
(It will set the hint depending on the user input. But this cannot be used for actual Auto completion, since you cannot change the suggestions on your keyboard, as far as I know):

```
TextInputEditText editText = ((TextInputEditText) textInputLayout.getEditText());
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        try {
            String userInput = s.toString();
            userInput = userInput.trim().toLowerCase();

            String match = null;
            for (String item : items) {
                if (item == null) continue;
                String fItem = item.trim().toLowerCase();
                if (fItem.startsWith(userInput)) {
                    match = item;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (match == null) editText.setHint(""); // Insert your default hint text here
            else editText.setHint(match);
        } catch (Throwable tr) {
            tr.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

### PREVIOUS

add the following as an attribute to your TextInputLayout:

```
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.*.ExposedDropdownMenu"
```

also did you implement your list_item.xml (which you called 'item' (R.layout.item from your code)) correctly?

---

That's what it says on the official page:

**In the layout:**

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    ...
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.*.ExposedDropdownMenu">
​
    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="none"
    />
​
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

**In code:**

```
val items = listOf("Material", "Design", "Components", "Android")
val adapter = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), R.layout.list_item, items)
(textField.editText as? AutoCompleteTextView)?.setAdapter(adapter)
```

**In the item layout (list_item.xml):**

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceSubtitle1"
/>
```

(https://material.io/components/text-fields/android#using-text-fields)

Comment: Thanks for your info but this isn't what I am asking. These codes open the dropdown menu. But I wanna auto-complete text on edit text as a hint like the above image. **AutoC**omplete -- AutoC must be text and "omplete" must be hint

Comment: Oh sorry I missinterpreted your sentence ("BUT the auto-complete-textview is suggesting the item on dropdown not on editText as a hint."). 
I don't think it is possible to set the auto complete results on your keyboard yourself, but if you only want the hint to work, you could add a textWatcher and check the user input against a list of possible inputs and if the user input matches the start of one of the list items then set the hint accordingly

Comment: @FurkanPaşaoğlu I edited my answer. Is it now what you need

Comment: Thank you @IntoVoid. Great algorithm but there is a problem. When I enter text to editText, hint will be gone. When I delete text, hint will be visible. So I can't show text and hint together

Comment: @FurkanPaşaoğlu That's true. You could add another textView behind it and set the hint text into it. You could use a RelativeLayout for this

Comment: @FurkanPaşaoğlu have u resolved this issue? If yes please share code with us thank you!